# Error installing create react app with code 7

Tags: create-react-app

This type of error creeps up when I am trying to install create react app with command line .How can I fix this problem ?

```
C:\Users\Rohit Mishra>npx create-react-app my-app
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\Rohit'
TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined
    at exit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:98:27)
    at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:216:3)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:77:20
    at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:225:22)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:263:24
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:83:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:82:13
    at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at afterExtras (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:173:20)
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:98
  var doExit = npm.config.loaded ? npm.config.get('_exit') : true
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined
    at exit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:98:27)
    at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:216:3)
    at process.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at process._fatalException (internal/bootstrap/node.js:496:27)
Install for create-react-app@latest failed with code 7
```

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6512

Answer (score 3):

The issue is occurring because you have space between your computer username.
You can resolve this by not installing your create-react-app package globally.

Use these commands :-

```
1. npm cache clean --force
2. npm install create-react-app --force
3. npm fund
4. npx create-react-app <app-name>
```